# Node.js, Promises & Recursion - Possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, paypal, promise

I want to retrieve transactions from paypal until there is no more transactions to retrieve.
I would like to do it while using recursive function.
I do not manage to figure out how to do it. 
Is it possible?

I can do the recursion but no to aggregate the transactions and pass them out of the function.

I removed non relevant lines for simplicity.

```
this.retrieveAllTransactionsBetween = function(end_date, start_date) { 
    return getTransactions({
                STARTDATE: Moment(start_date).format().replace('+00:00', 'Z'),
                ENDDATE: Moment(end_date).format().replace('+00:00', 'Z')
            })
            .then(function(transactions){
                if (end) { // test for end of transactions
                    return [];
                }
                console.log('finish transactions in iteration where earliest was',earliest.toDate());
                return transactions.concat(retrieveAllTransactionsBetween(earliest.toDate(), start_date, customer_id));
            })
            .catch(function(e){
                console.error('getAllTransactionsBetween general error', e);
            })
    ;
};

this.getTransactions = function(dates) {
    var stringified_api_call_param = QueryString.stringify(api_call_params);

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var sequence = Sequence.create();
        sequence
            .then(function (next) {
                api_call_options.headers = {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(stringified_api_call_param)
                    }
                ;

                var req = https.request(api_call_options, paypal_helpers.paypalCallbackWrapper(next));
                req.on('error', function(e) {
                    return reject(e.message);
                });
                req.write(stringified_api_call_param);
                req.end();
            })
            .then(function (next, res){
                return resolve(res);
            });
    });
};
```

Comment: you need a collection variable above the scope of your nested functions. it doesn't have to be global, it just needs to be defined as a sibling of your main routine so that inner functions can reach it. you can also bind() an object/array to one of the inner functions, give it a name, and then use that within the inner functions to reach the collection as _this_, which is un-used otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is wrong:

```
 return transactions.concat(retrieveAllTransactionsBetween(earliest.toDate(), start_date, customer_id));
```

You want to *wait* for the recursive call, `.concat` is an array function. You should wait for it:

```
 return retrieveAllTransactionsBetween(earliest.toDate(), start_date, customer_id).
        then(function(more){ return transactions.concat(more); });
```

Comment: Yes!
Thank you, this is what I was missing. Wonderful!